# Easy way to add change Id's to older git commits?

Tags: linux, git, version-control, gerrit, rebase

I have seven commits I need to add change IDs to. I see a lot of people say to use interactive git rebase. I'm not familiar with rebasing, and I'm having trouble with the files and functions that I changed the name of reverting back when I try and reword them to add change IDs.
Is there any other way to add change IDs? Or how do I stop my files/functions reverting back when I try and rebase. Once I abort the rebase, they go back to how I had them.
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "add change IDs"?

Comment: No, there is no other way. And you really have to learn [rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, and note you will need to
`push` and [Submit] *one commit at a time*:

1. Set the **Gerrit Hook** to add the Change-ID as you `commit` (or `amend`)
2. Create a new branch for your changes
3. For each of the changes, starting with the OLDEST, do:

   - `git cherry-pick ...`
   - `git commit --amend`  (this should add a Change-ID - different one each time)
   - (push the change to Gerrit - however you do that)
   - In Gerrit - approve and [Submit] this change
   - In your branch, again, do `git pull --rebase`